# What is the difference between declaring a view variable to using it directly on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, view

In Kotlin, as I know, you can call a view in two ways:

1. Declaring a variable

   ```
   val btn: Button = btnLogin
   btn.text = "newLogin"
   ```
2. Using it directly

   ```
   btnLogin.text= "newLogin"
   ```

So what are the differences between these implementations?

I know that declaring a variable may be more useful when calling repeatedly and may prevent typos, but what are the advantages?

Comment: None. I don't even see why declaring a new variable may prevent typos.

Comment: The code may have many views with similar ids, if you call one view multiple times it may lead to picking one wrong by mistake

Comment: If you're calling multiple functions consecutively on the same object, use `apply` or `run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `btnLogin` is a nullable property, then declaring a local variable allows you to acquire a non-null reference after checking for null. For example:

```
private var btnLogin: Button? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View) {
  btnLogin = view.findViewById(R.id.my_button)
}

private fun otherMethod() {
  val loginButton = btnLogin
  if (loginButton != null) {
    loginButton.doX()
    loginButton.doY()
    loginButton.doZ()
  }
}
```

Since the property can be changed from non-null to null at any time, capturing the current value to a local variable allows you to capture a fixed value at the point where it's declared. Kotlin does have many other constructs you can use instead of capturing a local variable, however. For example, this would be equivalent:

```
btnLogin?.let { loginButton ->
  loginButton.doX()
  loginButton.doY()
  loginButton.doZ()
}
```

In general, capturing a local variable just ensures that the same value is referenced throughout, but in most cases, it's likely not necessary.